# Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null. How to solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I built a project in Windows for Android and tested it in my android device, everything was okay. Then I carried my project folder to MacOs computer to test my app for Ios devices. Now I've some problems:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in the ios folder?

Comment: Of course I did

Comment: try  `react-native link`  and `cd ios && pod install `

Comment: Nothing is changed.

Answer (score -1):

try this command in your project directory

> npm install
>    or 
>   yarn